# Good vb script policy

Tags: windows, usb, vbscript

I have been seeing a lot of cases of the [H worm](http://www.fireeye.com/blog/technical/threat-intelligence/2013/09/now-you-see-me-h-worm-by-houdini.html) on USB sticks in the past few months.  It seems by default a vbs script will run on any computer even if it comes from an outside source (like a USB stick).  That means a lot of people or unwittingly infecting themselves when they try to use an infected USB stick!

Is there a good company policy for VBS files to address this issue?  I know you can [enforce singed scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156597.aspx), [restrict scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198679.aspx), or [disable all scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198684.aspx).  Are those good decisions?  Are there common services that users need which will stop working if I disable/restrict scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your business use of Office. Many organisations rely on Office macros to deliver business automation so turning them off completely isn't an option.

The most important first step is to ensure correct security on all PC's

- All users (including admins) must log in as standard users (admins should have very restricted profiles so that they cannot do things like email and office macros when logged in with an administrator account)
- All PC's must have good anti-virus software
- All PC's must be configured to on run white-listed applications - this is far and away the best protection currently available. At a pinch, if you are lacking a suitable enterprise security tool, you can use the free EMET tool from Microsoft which provides some security.
- If you have a suitable infrastructure for issuing certificates, you should enforce signed scripts only
- If you cannot issue certificates easily, I'd recommend allowing scripts to run only from specific trusted locations and keeping control that way. Maybe only allow documents in that location after a review process?
- Certainly scripts should be blocked when documents are opened from any untrusted location such as a USB stick & email.
- Under no circumstances should scripts ever be allowed to run directly from emails.

It was interesting that a recent security check, that I saw the output of, managed to compromise an entire network by sending a document containing a script from a GMail account to a system administrator! They of all people should know better but clearly don't, they overrode the security warning.